# Writing Script to remove contents of Directory

Tags: macos, scripting

Relatively new to the command line and scripting so bear with me. I am trying to remove all files in this file path:

```html
~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Templates
```

My current script looks like:

```html
#!/bin/sh

rm -Rfd "/Users/$user/Library/Group\ Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User\ Content/Templates/*" 2> /dev/null

exit 0
```

I can't figure out how to get this script to run correctly and remove the contents of *Templates*. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the end of your rm command: `2> /dev/null`. This is redirecting errors to `/dev/null/`, so you won't see them. You could also run your command directly in a shell. No need to create a separate file for it.